# How to run a single Scala test class without using testSourceDirectory and sourceDirectory maven pom tags (adding them disallows Java imports)

Tags: java, scala, maven, visual-studio-code

Inside pom.xml configuration file for maven I notice when a add those tags (testSourceDirectory and sourceDirectory) under the build tag they cause an issue with not being able to import java from the same project into scala files. When I remove them the scalatest-maven-plugin will throw a ClassNotFoundException if I add a single class using the jUnitClasses tag for the scalatest-maven-plugin configuration but it fixes the java import into scala file issue.

I don't want to wait for every single test class to run if I'm just trying to work on one new class.  I have searched everywhere and had no luck with anything. And no, trying to run a single test class via the mvn command line does not work either. Is there any work around for this so I can test single Scala tests and be able to import Java files from the same project?

Sample tags I had to remove to get Java importing into Scala and the ones commented out I tried as a fix:

```
<build>
<sourceDirectory>src/main/scala</sourceDirectory><testSourceDirectory>src/test/scala</testSourceDirectory>
<!-- <sourceDirectory>src/main/scala, src/main/java</sourceDirectory><testSourceDirectory>src/test/scala, src/test/java</testSourceDirectory> -->
</build>
```

The way I would run a single test before using Scala:

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.scalatest</groupId>
        <artifactId>scalatest-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0</version>
        <configuration>
            <!-- Comma separated list of JUnit test class names to execute -->
            <jUnitClasses>org.myorg.s3.TestS3Handler</jUnitClasses>
```

The stupid error I get now when I run "mvn test":

```
[INFO] --- scalatest-maven-plugin:2.0.0:test (test) @ s3-geoserver ---
*** RUN ABORTED ***
  java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.myorg.s3.TestS3Handler
  at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:476)
  at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:594)
  at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:527)
  at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
  at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:398)
  at org.scalatest.junit.JUnitWrapperSuite.<init>(JUnitWrapperSuite.scala:53)
  at org.scalatest.tools.Runner$.$anonfun$doRunRunRunDaDoRunRun$9(Runner.scala:1242)
  at scala.collection.immutable.List.map(List.scala:293)
  at org.scalatest.tools.Runner$.doRunRunRunDaDoRunRun(Runner.scala:1241)
  at org.scalatest.tools.Runner$.$anonfun$runOptionallyWithPassFailReporter$24(Runner.scala:1031)
```

I have been working with it for years and it still sucks the life out of me with how the configuration system is set up.

**EDIT:**
**I have fixed the issue by using IntelliJ instead of VSCode. I also removed the sourceDirectory and testSourceDirectory tags and deleted the scalatest-maven-plugin.  That leaves me with only scala-maven-plugin as the only scala-related plugin. After importing the project in IntelliJ I can click to run the JUnit test methods and the Java imports from the same project work fine.**

Comment: Is the [document](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-testing) help?

Comment: @JialeDu
I added an edit with my solution ;)